# Get resource ID of the icon of another android application

Tags: android, resources, icons

Is there a way to get the **resource ID** of the icon of another android app? (ex. `com.android.systemui.R.drawable.ic_xxx`)

I tried `context.getApplicationInfo().icon` but it returned a long integer. 
Is this possible?

Thanks

Comment: There is no way to get the resource ID of a Drawable in your desired format (com.android.systemui.R.drawable.ic_xxx) at runtime. The resource IDs refer to automatically created static Integer fields in the R.java class. However, you can get the entire Drawable. Check out my answer below.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can get the `Drawable` icon of an app by using:

```
Drawable icon = getPackageManager().getApplicationIcon( PACKAGE_NAME );
```

If you are interested in the resource ID of a Drawable of your own app, try this:

```
int resourceID = getResources().getIdentifier( DRAWABLE_NAME , "drawable", PACKAGE_NAME );
```

Or, if you care about performance, this version is quicker, but uses reflection:

```
try {
      Class resource = R.drawable.class;
      Field field = resource.getField( DRAWABLE_NAME );
      int drawableId = field.getInt(null);
    } catch (Exception e) {}
```

Comment: Is there a way to get int resource id of other application drawable.?

Comment: @AmitKumarKhare any luck?

Comment: @Tanasis haven't found any solution yet. :/

Answer (score 2):

This method should work for getting the app icon of an application, including yours:

```
String appPackageName=...; //use getPackageName() in case you wish to use yours
final PackageManager pm=getPackageManager();
final ApplicationInfo applicationInfo=pm.getApplicationInfo(packageName,PackageManager.GET_META_DATA);
final Resources resources=packageManager.getResourcesForApplication(applicationInfo);
final Bitmap appIconBitmap=BitmapFactory.decodeResource(resources,applicationInfo.icon);
```