# ResolveInfo getIconResource() giving really strange results (incorrect icons)

Tags: java, android, arraylist, android-arrayadapter, android-package-managers

I'm creating a list of applications installed on the phone. I'm retrieving all installed application with the `PackageManager`and `ResolveInfo`. Due to memory issue i'm using `getIconResource()` instead of `loadIcon()`.

My question is how do i display the correct icons in an imageView using the iconResource, the int?

**EDIT: added code**

this is the part where i create a list with installed apps get stored in an Arraylist `apps`

```
private void loadApps(){
        manager = getPackageManager();
        apps = new ArrayList<AppDetail>();

        if(apps.size()==0) {
            Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN, null);
            i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
            List<ResolveInfo> availableActivities = manager.queryIntentActivities(i, 0);
            for (ResolveInfo ri : availableActivities) {
                AppDetail app = new AppDetail();
                app.label = ri.loadLabel(manager);
                app.name = ri.activityInfo.packageName;
                app.icon = ri.activityInfo.getIconResource();
                app.allowed = false;
                apps.add(app);
            }
            Log.i("applist", apps.toString());
        }
    }
```

In an ArrayAdapter i want put the set the icons in an ImageView

```
ImageView appIcon = (ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.item_app_icon);
            int id = apps.get(position).icon;
            appIcon.setImageResource(id);
```

This is the result on the phone, its displaying strange icons (some apps even use google plus icons:

[image]

It also gives errors about not finding the resource:

`W/ResourceType﹕ getEntry failing because entryIndex 1 is beyond type entryCount 1
 W/ResourceType﹕ Failure getting entry for 0x7f030001 (t=2 e=1) in package 0 (error -2147483647)
 W/ImageView﹕ Unable to find resource: 2130903041`

Comment: have you tried [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11961599/get-resource-id-of-the-icon-of-another-android-application) ?

Comment: I edited the answer with the problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem was that i was retrieving the images from the wrong place. This was the code for getting te right icons:

```
ImageView appIcon = (ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.item_app_icon);
            String packageName = apps.get(position).name.toString();

            try {
                Drawable icon = getPackageManager().getApplicationIcon(packageName);
                appIcon.setImageDrawable(icon);
            } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```